# Windows batch file: get folders' path and store them in variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello I need a batch file to store in a variable all paths of all directories/subdirectories named ".svn" that I can found in my_folder.

Something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /r my_folder %%X IN (.svn) DO (ECHO %%X)
```

the command above prints them to screen, but I need to store them in a variable as a list of strings. Someone knows how to do it?

This is the site I use for helping myself with batch files: http://ss64.com/nt/

After I want to pass the value of such variable to the command `RD` in order to delete them along with this subfolders/files.
So let's say the variable is names `$a` i will do something like:

```
RD /s /q $a
```

Comment: I assume you are in windows right?

Comment: @DavidBrunelle yep, see 1st word in question's title. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution without any variables is to issue the `RD` command inside your `FOR` loop. You can use multiple commands inside the braces like:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /r my_folder %%X IN (.svn) DO (
    ECHO %%X
    RD /s /q %%X
)
```

If yo need the to add the pathes to a variable you can do it like that:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PATH_LIST=
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION   

FOR /r my_folder %%X IN (.svn) DO (
    ECHO %%X
    SET PATH_LIST=!PATH_LIST! "%%X"
)

ENDLOCAL

RD /s /q %PATH_LIST%
```

But keep in mind that environment variables are limited in size. In Windows XP a single variable can hold a max. of 8,192 bytes.